# ADF load data from CSV in sequence present in file

Tags: azure-data-factory

My CSV files data like

100,data1,data2,data3

200,data1,data2,data3

300,data1,data2,data3

300,data1,data2,data5

200,data1,data2,data3

300,data1,data2,data3

When i load the data into my table using  ADF dataflow it change the sequence of row. I want data to be loaded into the table as same row sequence present into the file like; I always want the rows be 100 then 200 and 300 belong to that and then next set of 200 and 300 belong.
It works for small data files but for large data files it does not maintain the row sequence. Looks like some kind data buffer and bulk load trigger it, is their a way i can force load rows one at a time as it present in file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Sort transformation, sorting the first column as the sort column. Also set the number of partitions in the Sort transformation under Optimize to "single partition". You need to do this because Mapping Data Flows is a scale-out feature built on Spark that will distribute data across nodes and partitions, losing your macro sort order, unless you force it into a single partition.

Comment: I can not sort by first column as it will combine 100, 200 and 300, i do not want that i want sequence to be like in file like rows 100,200,300,300,200,300.

Comment: Add a Surrogate Key transformation, which will give you an incrementing counter for each row. Use the same technique I described above but use the surrogate key column as the sort column. If you do not wish to include that column in your output sink, remove it from your sink mapping.